# Haar classifier for segmenting lips

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, haar-classifier

I have tried building my own Haar for segmenting out lips. But I have not achieved very good results. Can I get any Haar for lips segmentation just like the one we have for eyes. I searched the internet for such haar but couldn't find one.

My aim is to find if my mouth is widely open or closed.

If no one has done such haar. I will build one and opensource it.

Comment: Have you considered looking at OpenCV?  Also, take a look at the MEXOpenCV project: http://www.cs.stonybrook.edu/~kyamagu/mexopencv/ .  This wonderful dude has written MATLAB wrappers for most of the OpenCV libraries and headers so you can use Haar directly from this.

Comment: Yes. Here s the collection of all Haar from that project : https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades
It does not have the haar for lips.

Answer (score 2):

If there are no Haar cascades in the OpenCV distribution that currently implement how to segment out lips, consider building your own.  Take a look at the guide to building Haar cascades from the OpenCV project for more details:

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html

I am assuming you already have positive and negative examples of what you want to classify, and so you can build your own cascades using your own ground truth data.  The above guide will get you started on creating your own Haar cascades.

**NB:** I am usually *against* deferring people to external links without some sort of closure in my posts, but the process to do this is quite involved, and I can't invest the effort in repeating that information here.

Answer (score 1):

This will help u in matlab use Viola-Jones algorithm
[vision.CascadeObjectDetector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.cascadeobjectdetector-class.html) System object

Detect objects using the Viola-Jones algorithm 
Description

The cascade object detector uses the Viola-Jones algorithm to detect people's faces, noses, eyes, mouth, or upper body. You can also use the [Training Image Labeler](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/label-images-for-classification-model-training.html) to train a custom classifier to use with this System object. For details on how the function works, see [Train a Cascade Object Detector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/train-a-cascade-object-detector.html).